# In how many ways can you divide bonuses between employees?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

How many ways are there to divide 33 000 USD between 22 employees of a company (including 1 president, 1 vice-chairman and 20 normal employees), if a normal employee can get 1000 or 1500 USD, whereas both president and vice-chairman can get: 0, 1500 or 3000 USD?

Comment: I have 41043 ways. The numerical value for 20 choose 14 is incorrect. Otherwise I agree.

Comment: not sure where i got that value for $\binom{20}{14}$ but thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming we have to distribute all \$33,000, the fact that each normal employee gets \$1,000 or \$1,500 means we have to distribute at least \$3,000 to the executives.

Since there are three ways to distribute \$3,000 to our executives, that leaves exactly \$30,000 to distribute to the employees. That can happen only 1 way, every one gets \$1,500.

Since there are two ways to distribute \$4,500 to our executives, that leaves $\binom{20}{17}$ ways to distribute 3 \$1,000 bonuses and 17 \$1,500 bonuses amongst the 20 employees.

Since there is only one way to distribute \$6,000 to our executives, that leaves $\binom{20}{14}$ ways to distribute 6 \$1,000 bonuses and 14 \$1,500 bonuses amongst the 20 employees.

Thus the total is 
$$
3\binom{20}{20}+2\binom{20}{17}+\binom{20}{14}=3+2280+38,760=41,043.
$$

Answer (score 2):

You tagged this as generating functions, so I'll provide the generating function as well. Since each normal employee can get 1000 or 1500, we have $e(x) = (x^{1000} + x^{1500})$. There are 20 such employees, so we consider $(e(x))^{20}$. Now the executives can get $0, 1000, 1500$, so we have $f(x) = (1 + x^{1500} + x^{3000})$. There are two executives, so we consider $(f(x))^{2}$. Now our generating function is $g(x) = (e(x))^{20} * (f(x))^{2}$. You can factor $x^{20000}$ out from $(e(x))^{20}$, which leaves you looking for the coefficient of $x^{13000}$ as opposed to $x^{33000}$.

Comment: I started thinking about this as a generating function problem, but it seemed like overkill. The combinatorial argument below captures all of the pertinent calculations from the generating function multiplication. Get a vote up from me!

Comment: I like your argument better since it captures everything with a better intuition. It's been a while since I've done a ton of combinatorics (aside from graph theory, but most of my work there is algebraic), and I've lost my edge. I find generating functions do a lot of the work for me, and they're easier to think about. Combinatorics is all about the thought process though!